# Scale the Axis in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, tikzscale

I have the following problem:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, >=latex]
\draw[->] (-6,0) -- (6,0) node[right] {\scriptsize $x$};
\draw[->] (0,-5) -- (0,15) node[above] {\scriptsize $y$};
\foreach \x in {-5,...,5} \draw (\x, 1pt) -- (\x,-3pt) node[anchor=north] {\tiny \x};
\foreach \y in {-4,-2,...,14} \draw (1pt,\y) -- (-3pt,\y) node[anchor=east] {\tiny \y};
\draw[color=black, thick, domain=-0.8:3.8, samples=100]   plot (\x,{-3*(\x)^2+9*(\x)+6}) node[right] {\tiny $f(x)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

I want the y Axis to be smaller like the xAxis. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Try `[scale=0.5, >=latex, y=.5cm]`.

Answer (score 6):

Leave it to `pgfplots` or use TikZ' `datavisualization` library;

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,enlargelimits]
\addplot[domain=-1:4] {-3*x^2+9*x+6} node[left]{$f(x)$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Substituting the lines 6-7 with:

```
\foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \sy using \y/2] in {-4,-2,...,14} \draw (1pt,\sy) -- (-3pt,\sy) node[anchor=east] {\tiny \y};
\draw[color=black, thick, domain=-0.8:3.8, samples=100]   plot (\x,{(-3*(\x)^2+9*(\x)+6)/2}) node[right] {\tiny $f(x)$};
```

should work as expected.